# java 8 - Group by after split comma separated String

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of object which contains id, information. Each id have more than one information with comma-separated value. I want to count each information count by group by id.

Pojo :

```
class InformationData{
     private Integer id;
     private String information;
     private Integer count;

}
```

Example data :

```
id   information
Z01  blue, green
Z01  green, yellow
C10  blue
C10  green, red
```

Expected OP :

```
id   information count
Z01  blue        1
Z01  green       2
Z01  yellow      1
C10  blue        1
C10  green       1
C10  red         1
```

How to do this using Java 8 Stream?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Is id Integer or String. You declared it as Integer, but Z01 doesn't look like an Integer.

Comment: @Eran Its an Integer only. I just gave an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can produce a `Stream` of all the pairs of IDs and information. Then you can do double grouping, and count the elements of each group.

```
List<InformationData> data = ...
Map<Integer,List<String,Long>> counts = 
data.stream()
    .flatMap(dat -> Stream.of(dat.getInformation().split(","))
                          .map(inf -> new SimpleMapEntry<>(dat.getID(),inf)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                   Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                         Collectors.counting())));
```

You can also do it with a single `groupingBy`, assuming your `InformationData` overrides `equals` and has the relevant constructor.

```
Map<InformationData,Long> counts = 
data.stream()
    .flatMap(dat -> Stream.of(dat.getInformation().split(","))
                          .map(inf -> new InformationData(dat.getID(),inf)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting()));
```

EDIT: Seeing that you edited your question, and now `InformationData` has a count property, you can use the `Map<InformationData,Long>` produced by the previous snippet to produce a `List<InformationData>` that contains the counts:

```
List<InformationData> counts = 
data.stream()
    .flatMap(dat -> Stream.of(dat.getInformation().split(","))
                          .map(inf -> new InformationData(dat.getID(),inf)))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new InformationData (e.getKey().getID(),e.getKey().getInformation(),e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT: since `Collectors.counting()` returns `Long`, you should either change the `count` property of your `InformationData` class to `Long`, or replace `Collectors.counting()` with the less elegant `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)`.

Comment: Updated the question. Can we map the data to List<InformationData> counts = data.stream()...?

Comment: @MMMMS how do you suggest to store the counts in a `List<InformationData>`? Perhaps a `Map<InformationData,Long>`?

Comment: we can map count to InformationData's count object ?

Comment: @MMMMS see edit

Comment: Tried, but getting Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)

Comment: @MMMMS I may have some typo. Can you post the full code of the `InformationData` class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207169/discussion-between-mmmms-and-eran).

Comment: @MMMMS please see my edit